# How to show inital value in jsp form

Tags: spring, jsp

I am using jsp . And I just want to show a value (maxHolidays which is 15) in my form. But I always get exception  Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

This is my code

Controller

```
int maxHolidays = 15;
model.addAttribute("maxHolidays", maxHolidays);
```

jsp File

```
<form:form method="POST" >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <label class="control-label">Max holiday length</label>


                                            <form:input type="text" path="maxHolidays" id="maxHolidays" 
                                                class="form-control" 
                                                required="required" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="maxHolidays" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code in jsp page

```
value="${maxHolidays}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="has-error">
   <span class="help-inline">${maxHolidays}</span>                                             
</div>
```